# Flatten a list and a string

Tags: python

I am know how to easily flatten a list of lists.
For example:

```
my_list = [['abc'],[1,2,3]]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list))
```

But if

```
my_list = ['abs',[1,2,3]]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list))
```

I get `['a','b','c',1,2,3]`, while I want `['abc', 1,2,3]`

I can solve this problem by running a `for loop` for the second element in the original list, but that seems like a messy way to do it, and becomes really messy if you don't know which element in a list is a list, and which is a string.

Is there a simple way to flatten a list that has both lists and string in it?

Comment: Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/2588818) answer but put a check for string types. I'd say how to do that but it's different whether you're using Python 2 or Python 3, and you haven't said.

Comment: Ok, then: `[item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist if not isinstance(sublist, basestring)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` with a `lambda` function

```
l = lambda x,y: (x if isinstance(x,list) else [x]) + (y if isinstance(y,list) else [y])
reduce(l, my_list)
```

#### Example

```
>>> my_list = [['abc'],[1,2,3]]
>>> reduce(l, my_list)
['abc', 1, 2, 3]

>>> my_list = ['abs',[1,2,3]]
>>> reduce(l, my_list)
['abs', 1, 2, 3]
```

That way, you literally **reduce** a list of separte things to one list of these things.

It works with as many lists inside lists you want.
For instance:

```
>>> my_list = ['abs',[1,2,[3,4]]]
>>> tmp = reduce(l, my_list)
#tmp = ['abs', 1, 2, [3,4]] - Just run again
>>> reduce(l, tmp)
>>> ['abs', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It should be noticed that this is not an efficient method, as highlighted by Two-bit Alchemist

Comment: Note that `reduce` + `lambda` is pretty inefficient in Python and some IDEs and linters (e.g. pylint) will complain about it.